# Nested sequence of directories

Tags: command-line

I am making nested directories using a command like this:

```
mkdir -p 1/2/3/4
```

However, for many nested directories it takes too much time.

If I want to create 100 directories, what should I do?

Comment: You really want to make so many directories? You can always automate using scripts.

Comment: Actually I am new to CLI so I just wanted to try out things. How can I automate using scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You can run:

```bsh
mkdir -p $(printf "%s" {1..100}/)
```

where [brace expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) is used with `/` as the optional `<SUFFIX>` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @MominAdnan You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **for** loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

p=''
for i in {1..100}; do
  p+=$i/
done
mkdir -p "$p"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works